# How to use Cast SDK in Google Slides like app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

So I've been working on a type of slide/power point app. I've been trying to find out whether or not Cast SDK is applicable. Ideally, I'd want to cast a Fragment (exactly like Slides), leaving the navigation bar(RecyclerView) only visible to the presenter.

<s>As far as I know, Cast SDK only supports Media formats. However, I wonder how Slides work in that case then? Does it convert every slide to JPGs or something like that?</s>

I found out that I could extend `CastPresentation` class but what if I want to cast a fragment that already extends Fragment?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media Do realize that the images are limited to 720p even if the display is 4K (search on complaints about Google Photos casting to Chromecast Ultra)

Comment: I've already gone through that. I'm not intending to cast images but rather fragments which may contain images. 

Also found CastPresentation api but all examples I've found so far are 5-year outdated.